# error while using usermod when setting up docker

Tags: 16.04, users, docker

On an Azure Ubuntu 16.04LTS VM. I am trying to setup docker and I ran the command

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

at the end I tried to added my user to the docker group but I keep getting this error

```
$ usermod -a -G docker kumar
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting 
sent invalidate(group)request, exiting
```